# Complicated csv format: columns in two lines

Tags: python, pandas

The following is the (what I believe to be) very awkward header of a file I am diving into right now:

```
,,,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012
"Office","Office(code)","Origin"
"Albania","AL","Total",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6,49,87,201,390,395,116,420,541,402,349,21,,
```

That is, the first two lines **together** constitute the headers. Is there any way to apply `read_csv()` to this without any major hassle?

Comment: Read in both header lines, wich gives a MultiIndex, and then try to flatten the MultiIndex in a way. Would something like that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the first two lines manually, then pass the rest on to `read_csv`, i.e. something like:

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
    headers = f.readline().strip().split(',') # get years
    headers[:3] = f.readline().strip().split(',') # update first three columns
    data = pd.read_csv(f, names=headers)
```

Note that this will pass the file handle `f` to `read_csv` with the "read head" already at the start of the third line.